# Are vector subscripts standard C/C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

A [patch](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2012-04/msg01024.html) was posted to gcc that provides something called vector subscripting to g++ (gcc already had it).

If `a` is an array and `i` is an int then `i[a]` is legal and equal to `a[i]`.

```
double a[]{0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0}; // C++11 style but would work in C++98 style too.
assert(a[2] == 2.0);
assert(2[a] == 2.0);
```

So, is this legal and standard C/C++ or is it a gcc extension?

Actually, Google shows MS Developer Studio has this too.  I looked in the C++ standard and didn't see it though.

Comment: Since `*(ptr+i)` and `ptr[i]` expressions are identical, the answer flows nicely from the commutativity of addition. If I see anyone on my team use this "feature", he'll be fired on the spot.

Comment: Yes, it's counter-intuitive and would surprise people looking through code.  Also, luckily it works by pointer arithmetic rather than some lexical rule so it won't work for, say, std::vector or std::array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C arrays why is this true? a\[5\] == 5\[a\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The patch has nothing to do with `i[a]` being equivalent to `a[i]`; that has always been the case, in both languages. Unless user-defined types are involved, `a[i]` is defined as being equivalent to `*(a+i)`, and addition is commutative.

The patch concerns [vector datatypes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html#Vector-Extensions) (not to be confused with the C++ `std::vector` class template), a GCC language extension to support vector processing instructions. According to the patch notes, they were subscriptable like arrays in C but not C++, and this patch adds that feature to C++.

Comment: Yet another "I'll be ...  WTF" moment in my C++ travels.  I see the rationale for this syntax too.  Thx.

Comment: OK, I finally followed the standard to expr.add p5 and dcl.array p6 where they say this.

Comment: not to be pedantic, but don't you mean that `a[i]` is `*(a+i)` for primitives or something like that? Because from what you are saying it sounds like a class with an dereference and addition operator would automatically get an `operator[]` which is obviously not the case.

Answer (score 5):

In C, this follows from the fact that `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a + b)`, which since `+` is [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) of course is the same as `*(b + a)`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is legal, as vector elements are assured to be contiguous in memory by the standard.

Note that:

```
a[i] == i[a] == *(a+i)
```